# Sublime Text 2 Vintage mode and Go To Line

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way tu use Vim's standard `Goto line (:number)` in Vintage Mode?

Currently I have to use `Ctrl+g`.

Comment: Do you means type `42G` or `42gg` in command line mode to go to line 42? It should be supported.

Comment: I mean colon + line number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started using Vintage mode only yesterday, so this may not be the best solution. Anyway as far as I understand Vintage mode doesn't implement all the command line functionality of Vim.

To enable `Goto line (:number)` I installed the [VintageEx](https://github.com/SublimeText/VintageEx) package. You can do it from the Package Manager.

Hope this help. Happy coding!

Comment: This does not appear to be working in 2023 :(